# Error after upgrade Google Play Services to 11.0.0 version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I have a strange issue. After uploading Google Play Services library from version 10.2.6 to version 11.0.0, when i try to compile I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>    Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.0.

I visited the link mentioned in the error and the last version of the google-services plugin seems to be 3.1.0, ie the version i am using, and i have already upgraded all the play services libraries to 11.0.0 version. What can I do to compile my code with 11.0.0 version of GMS?

Here's my build.gradle file (module scope):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 23
        versionName "0.7.3.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789",
                            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        prontopro {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "TEST_ENVIRONMENT", "false"
        }

        prontoproTest {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "TEST_ENVIRONMENT", "true"
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
    //reactive libraries
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.8.2@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:0.8.0'
    compile 'com.hwangjr.rxbus:rxbus:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.f2prateek.rx.preferences:rx-preferences:1.0.2'
    //testing
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.6.3'
    //onesignal
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.4@aar'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.1.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And finally here's my build.gradle file (app scope):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should delete the line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Because `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` already has same package.

That's where the conflict arises.

**UPDATE:**

Use Play services version `11.0.1`

Comment: Woops this solution seems to create another strange bug. Now if i try to build i get this: "error: cannot find symbol class ConnectionResult", the full name of the class is com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult

Comment: I tried using this class, using your build.gradle, it works fine for me. Try cleaning the project and then updating Play services in the SDK Manager

Comment: I tried everything but it doesn't work, I can't compile. But i've found a possibile problem in Play Services 11 Release notes. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases it says:
 "An issue in SDK version 11.0.0 is impacting apps with [rxjava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex/rxjava) dependencies, both direct and transitive."

Comment: If you do this while also using `FirebaseAuth` **like me**, you'll get error `Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.yourpackage.yourpackage. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508542/1468531) if you are in a similar situation as me. Maybe that SO post will help you as it has helped me.

Comment: @MattiaRuggiero Yeah the SDK might be broken

Comment: Why not using `11.0.1`.. and you don't need to delete that line

Comment: Yes Abhishek Singh, i solved the problem using 11.0.1 version ;)

Comment: i have apply plugin: 'com.android.application' and no line like compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'   but nothing is working

Answer (score 6):

Use play Service Version `12.0.0` and

in project level gradle use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`

**EDIT** Answer updated to latest version

Comment: Yes, it seems that they fixed the problem in 11.0.1 version. Better late than never :)

Answer (score 1):

After a major update of Android Studio, clean an rebuild your project.Better You can use version 10.

Comment: Thanks but clean and rebuild didn't work :( version 10 of play services works, but i want to upgrade to version 11

Answer (score 1):

You probably all ready fixed the issue, but updating Firebase plugin also to 11.0.1 fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @KNR do not post identical answers

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was the following

Project Gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

App Gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

dependencies

```
//    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:+'
compile project(':paymentGatewayCommons')
compile project(':paypal')
compile project(':paytm')
compile project(':payu')
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0.pr1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0.pr1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0.pr1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:11.0.1'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.0.1'
compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Yeah, version 11.0.1 of Play Services library fixed the problem, as said by Abhishek Singh

Comment: not just that, commenting out appindexing and contextmanager was also needed to be done. just 11.0.1 did not work for me.

Comment: I didn't use those two libraries in my project, as you can see in the build.gradle file that i posted above

Comment: Can you paste the gradle set that worked for you ? I am happy to delete my answer, if the one that is accepted solves my issue. My issue was "not" solved with accepted answer, and I thought it will help someone looking for an answer.  My intent is to improve the quality of the answer.

Comment: The gradle set that worked for me is the same that i posted in the original answer, the only difference is version 11.0.1 of Play Services library instead of version 11.0.0. Original solution posted by dustblue (You should delete the line apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' because apply plugin: 'com.android.application' already has same package.) didn't work for me because version 11.0.0 of Play Services library had a strange issue when used together with rxjava2 library. Finally version 11.0.1 worked pretty well, it seems that Google have fixed the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting directly the required servies like if you want to get SmsRetriver compile

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.0.1'
```

Rather Than

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
```