# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. Update version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.6

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In through Firebase into my Android app and the following message keeps appearing after my Gradle sync:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.6.

How can I fix this error?

Here's my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sjf.lgcats"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/2'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the same version for all Firebase and Google Play libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
```

While your making changes, you could also use the latest version of build tools:

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
```

You can simplify maintenance of version numbers and ensure they are always consistent by doing this:

```
ext {
    SUPPORT_LIB_VER = '25.3.1'
    GOOGLE_LIB_VER = '11.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$GOOGLE_LIB_VER"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$GOOGLE_LIB_VER"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$GOOGLE_LIB_VER"
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: `ext { }` is really convenient! +1