# Updating the version Google Play Services to 11.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

When I try to sync the `gradle` file I keep on getting this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.0.

Before posting this question I have visited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456533/error-after-upgrade-google-play-services-to-11-0-0-version), because the error was similar to that of mine and according to the accepted answer I removed `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` and tried to sync it again and the `build was successfull`, but when I tried to run the app on my device it threw an error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
```

I have tried all the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456533/error-after-upgrade-google-play-services-to-11-0-0-version) link and even tried to change play service service version `11.0.0` to `11.0.1`, but none of them works.

Here is my build.gradle(module) file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hp.passwordStorage"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle(app) file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

- Go to File -> Project Structure
- Select 'Project Settings'
- Select 'Dependencies' Tab
- Click '+' and select '1.Library Dependencies'
- Search for : com.google.android.gms:play-services
- Select the latest version and click 'OK'

Comment: Doesn't work, I am getting this error : `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.0.`

Comment: Do you have Google Play Services installed in your SDK Manager? Try to add this line at the bottom of your app/build.gradle file: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: Can you try to put this `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'` in your build.gradle and remove the other firebase compile module

Comment: Error still persists `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.2.`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured both your **root-level Gradle file** and **module Gradle file** (usually the `app/build.gradle`). Check this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk) which can help you on how to integrate the Firebase libraries into your project. Also, the cause of this crash is likely to be the version of Google Play Service installed on the testing device. Make sure that you have the latest Google Play Services version installed on the testing device.

Comment: I am testing the application on a physical device and I have checked that it has the latest Google Play Services version installed, but the same error is displayed on the android monitor `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.2.`